# NSMutableArray EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on initWithObjects

Tags: objective-c

Is the following legal in Objective-c with ARC enabled?

```
NSMutableArray * smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4", "5", nil];
```

I thought it should be. However, in this situation it gives me EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on the forth line:

```
NSMutableArray * bigArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
[bigArray addObject: smallArray];
smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4", "5", nil];
```

addObject copies the pointer right? So if I allocate a new segment of memory to smallArray to point to, what is wrong with that?

However this code segment does not crash:

```
NSMutableArray * bigArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
[bigArray addObject: smallArray];
smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[smallArray addObject:@"4"];
[smallArray addObject:@"5"];
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Not very clear about this, but I happened to see `initWithObjects:@"4", "5", nil]`... have you lost `@` before `"5"`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4", "5", nil];
```

The second object must be **@"5"**, not just **"5"**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because you forgot the @ in the string "5". it should be:

```
smallArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4", @"5", nil];
```